# Promotion of products and suggestions for illegal product usage

Tags: discussion

In the last couple of questions I filed in here at AE I was advised to solve my issues by acquiring a Microsoft Windows licence.

I have been struggling to get TWRP to boot on one of my devices and on a first a reaction a user [directed me to do it with Windows](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180617/50942). While I regard this mostly as a raw attempt to help, even after I succeeded in flashing TWRP to the device from my system the same user [kept promoting Microsoft Windows](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180613/install-twrp-on-samsung-note-10-1#comment232402_180613).

In [a follow up question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180927/install-lineageos-on-samsung-note-10-1-without-twrp) I specifically stated I am not willing to acquire a Microsoft Windows licence. This lead not only to more promotion of Microsoft's system, but even to [a clear hint to use it illegally](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180927/install-lineageos-on-samsung-note-10-1-without-twrp#comment232923_180927).

I do not regard the behaviour of these two users particularly malicious (one at least is clearly trying to help), they are possibly just being somewhat careless. In other StackExchange sites this kind of behaviour would be less welcomed. So the question boils down to how tolerable this sort of product promotion should be at AE.

Comment: Perhaps you could specify in your questions what type of PC resources you have access to. Something like "I'm looking for solutions that will work with an Ubuntu PC" would probably suffice, and would (hopefully) avoid discussions/posturing about "Well why can't you use X instead?" since everyone's expectations would be set equally.

Comment: I see three downvotes on your question on main site. Could they be the result of meta effect?

Answer (score 7):

I didn't happen to see these questions and answers when they were posted. Coming to them afresh now, I'm going to ask you to consider if maybe you've read too much into this. As Andy Yan said, he uses Ubuntu as his main desktop. He's used both Odin and Heimdall, and based on this experience, he thinks the easiest way for you to achieve your goal is to use Samsung's official tool, even if this means using Windows as a one-off, or borrowing the use of a Windows PC from a friend or workplace.

Just consider how much easier he must think it must be, if it would be worth even that extra effort. Little wonder then, that when you persisted with trying to do it the hard way, got no help, and got stuck again, that he checked whether you *really* need to do it that way. That's not "promotion of Microsoft's system": it's just someone trying to find the expedient way, and taking care that you're not making things unnecessarily difficult for yourself because he hasn't made the trade-offs clear. I think that's the opposite of "careless".

Far from "tolerating" this kind of behaviour: we encourage it. Lots of users come here with problems and artificial constraints, and most of the time it's easier to remove the constraint than to work around it. You're welcome to hold out for an answer that involves fixing your Heimdall problem, or for one where you don't need to install a recovery at all, but you can't expect anyone to feel bad for telling you an easier answer, even if you have special reasons why you can't or won't follow it.

Comment: Hi Dan, I appreciate your answer. Just consider this issue from my perspective. To follow the suggestion that includes using Odin I would have start by acquiring a Microsoft Windows licence (99 €) and then install it. For that I would have to partition the hard drive, set up dual boot, install Windows and reinstall my system. That all could easily take me a couple of days. In contrast, installing `heimdall` and going through its manual took some dozens of minutes - it clearly was the most expedient procedure in my situation.

Comment: Another point here regards `heimdall`. I have not yet reached a definitive conclusion, but at this stage it does not look like it failed to flash TWRP. The conjecture that it is the cause of the boot failure might be precipitated.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much quicker it is to set up Heimdall if it doesn't work for you. And I don't think it's unreasonable for Andy to guess that you might be able to use someone else's computer, even if you know you can't.